# Windows Authentication in web.config in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to enable Windows Authentication from my `web.config`, without setting it in IIS.

I have the following elements in the `web.config`:

```
  authentication mode="Windows
  identity impersonate="true
```

However windows authentication is not working. How do I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Do you need this to work from Visual Studio ? IISExpress ?

Comment: Which version of IIS?

Comment: I need this to work in iis 7.0 or 7.5

Answer (score 16):

**For IIS Express**

You can set it up here. You may also wish to disable anonymous access

[image: Setting Windows auth for IIS Express]

**For IIS**

I found it was necessary to set this under `system.webServer`

```
<system.webServer>
    […]
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

This does almost the same thing as the @Dimitar suggestion - use IIS Manager to change the setting. The difference is that the config file avoids a manual step - but adds this next one:

**Note:**

By default, *IIS Feature Delegation* locks some of those settings (Basic & Windows auth), so you'll need to go to the root of the IIS server, and enable those to be *read/write*. E.g.:

[image: Feature delegation - Allowing read/write for auth section]

A more detailed description of [accessing Feature Delegation is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock/12343141#12343141).

Answer (score 8):

If by this you mean running your project from Visual Studio (IISExpress - not IIS), then you can try to do the following:

In Visual Studio -> Click on the root of your project -> Press F4 in order to open the properties pane -> Look for "Windows Authentication" and mark is as "Enabled" -> Run your project.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you must use IIS to enable Windows authentication. You cannot do it in Web.config alone. (At least up to IIS 8.5, the current version as of this post.)

This is because the Web.config elements for enabling Windows authentication (`<system.webServer><security><authentication><windowsAuthentication>`) can only be defined in applicationHost.config (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config).

Answer (score 2):

If windows authentication is not installed on IIS it won't work. If it is installed setting in web.config should be fine