# IIS Error This configuration section cannot be used at this path

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am facing a strange behavior in that I have an application thats hosted on two nodes. works fine on one node, on the other throws up the following error,

> Server Error in '/***_Service' Application.
>
> Configuration Error  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using `<location allowOverride="false">` from an inherited configuration file.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 34:      </context>
> Line 35:  </spring>
> Line 36:  <appSettings>
> ```

I have compared the applicationHost.config files on both the boxes and they are same. Not facing the problem in Dev environment too. Am I missing something? Can someone please give me some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock

Comment: i have read that question / solution. but doesnt seem to work. also a different case in which the app works on a node but doesnt on another.

Comment: Have you checked if the IIS setup varies? It could be related to the app being setup as a virtual app on one box and a virtual directory on the other box.