# MVC Site Deployed on IIS 8.5 Doesn't Like the <modules> Section

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl, web-config

I can't figure out what the exact problem is here. I created an MVC site and set it to be hosted on an Azure VM. But then I tried publishing it to my local IIS instead on my local machine (not on an Azure VM afterall, just for testing).

So anyways, I wanted to try and enable SSL connections to my server, so I set up an HTTPS binding on port 443 for my server and modified my hosts file to resolve 127.0.0.1 from www.mydomain.com, where "mydomain" is my test production URL.

I get this error when I try to access https://www.mydomain.com:

[image]

I get that it doesn't like the modules section in my Web.config, but removing it just causes it to snowball into a plethora of other Internal Server Errors...

What can I do to get my site running on Local IIS?

Here is my Site Binding:

- Type: https
- IP address: All Unassigned
- Port: 443
- Host name: www.mydomain.com
- SSL certificate: IIS Express Development Certificate

My site works fine when I run it on IIS Express, just not when I run it on Local IIS. The site is as bare-bones as it gets. I just used the template MVC site to make it.

As requested, the Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mydomain-20140729071121.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mydomain-20140729071121;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: At least post the contents of the web.config file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thanks, enabling all of the Application Development Features in Programs and Features solved my issues. Looks like I was missing some of them for Internet Information Services.