# Xamarin Forms - Consuming a Web Service written in Visual studio 2012

Tags: web-services, xamarin

I have written a simple web service in Visual Studio 2012.

When I test the web service in internet explorer I get the following result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"ID":1,"ConsultantName":"Jim",
"ConsultantEmailAddress":"Jim@xyz.com","ConsultantCellNumber":null,
"ConsultantPhoneNumber":null},{"ID":2,"ConsultantName":"Steve","ConsultantEmailAddress":"Steve@xyz.com",
"ConsultantCellNumber":null,"ConsultantPhoneNumber":null}]</string>
```

two records returned in JSON format

all looks fine

So now to call the web service in XAMARIN:

1. After a lot of research I found out that "LOCALHOST" means nothing in the ANDROID world - So I replace "LOCALHOST" with 10.0.2.2 and much more code got executed.
2. I looked at all the examples I could find on consuming web services and eventually settled on the modified code below:

In the code below it seems as if the request is successful when calling the web service however when the code tries to consume the result ( JSON string ) a  400 Bad Request  error occurs.

This is the line where the error occurs:

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

(This line is right at the bottom of the code included)

error - //  Remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

The code is below:
I would appreciate any comments or guidance.

Further to this it would be great if XAMARIN could put out a real simple example of consuming a web service. Every example I have seen so far has complications where if your knowledge is minimal you have to do tons of research before you can even understand the code.
What about a video with very simple code covering: Asynchronous Web consumption using XAMARIN Forms.
The problem I face is that I have spend three days fiddling. If I had a simple working example I could slowly increase the complexity until I fully understand what is going on, but now I still do not have an idea where my problem lies.

Thank you in anticipation.

```
    private async Task ExecuteLoadConsultants ()
    {

        Initialized = true;
        IsBusy = true;

        ConsultantInfo x = new ConsultantInfo{ ConsultantName = "WEwewewewe" };
            Consultants.Add (x);

        // call to webservice 

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = 
                       (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create ("http://10.0.2.2:53498/TennantMobileWS1.asmx?op=GetConsultantAll");
        webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);

        IsBusy = false;
    }



    private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation

        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        //Start the web request
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponceStreamCallback), request);

    }

    void GetResponceStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;


        //  Remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request on line below


        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to make a tunnel and get access to your localhost and for the bar request do this:

Click "Start button"
in the search box, enter "Turn windows features on or off"
in the features window, Click: "Internet Information Services"
Click: "World Wide Web Services"
Click: "Application Development Features"
Check (enable) the features. I checked all but CGI.

I got form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock/12867753#12867753)

I hope this help you :)

Credit to the appropriate