# BundleTransformer throwing strange exceptions from web.config

Tags: asp.net

I am using `BundleTransformer` for an ASP.NET MVC website, and everything works fine when I run the web application from Visual Studio (IIS Express), but when I attempt to load it up in a full-fledged IIS, I am getting a peculiar error message that I don't understand.

**Config Error**

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

**Config Source**
[image]

I'm really at a loss here, I have no idea what this could possibly mean or what I need to do to fix it. It is like I just cannot have a `<handlers>` section in my `web.config`.

I've found a lot of answers to questions regarding the 'locking', but that doesn't really seem to be the issue here.

Comment: And to confirm, you have checked config files of parent sites/servers, as well as system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config to make sure that none of the settings are disallowing override?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that, but I installed IIS out of the box using the Add/Remove Windows Features in Windows 8.1 x64 Professional, if that gives you any hints.

Comment: Not sure what default values are, in that case.  Try the steps here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12867753/1223642

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that on the development computer you are using IIS in **Integrated** mode, but on a production server in **Classic mode**.

You have 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. If on the server is installed IIS 7 or higher, then in settings of the application pool set `Integrated` to the **Managed Pipline Mode** property.
2. If you have old version of IIS, then remove the`/configuration/system.webServer` element from your `Web.config` file. Add the HTTP handlers to the `/system.web/httpHandlers` element (see the [“Debugging HTTP-handlers”](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging%20HTTP-handlers) section of documentation).