# Web.Config Configuration Error in App

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I've got application ready to upload it on hosting, but when I upload files on the server I'm getting this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Hosting Helpdesk said that they can't change server configurations, so there is my web.config file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location allowOverride="true">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Lampino.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
      <globalization uiCulture="pl-PL" culture="pl-PL" fileEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8"/>
      <compilation debug="true"/>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <securityPolicy>
        <trustLevel name="Full"/>
      </securityPolicy>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Is there any option that it will work on this hosting or should I find a new one? Maybe there really is a problem with my web.config file?

Did it same way as resolution of the IIS problem, but nothing has changed. Also I don't have access to server configurations...

**EDIT:**
When I removed trustLevel tag got this error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]

Source File: App_Web_fgajuxdi.0.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace: 


[SecurityException: Request failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(PermissionSet permSet, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
   System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand() +68
   System.Data.LocalDBAPI.DemandLocalDBPermissions() +241
   System.Data.LocalDBAPI.CreateLocalDBInstance(String instance) +32
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5308411
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +262
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +434
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +225
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +321
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +67
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +121
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +316
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +86
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1482
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.GetData() +56
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) +173
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +63
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.DataBind() +54
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.EnsureDataBound() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.CreateChildControls() +72
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6704
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +245
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
   ASP.index_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in App_Web_fgajuxdi.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Comment: I can understand the connection string and the ui culture. Do you need the rest of the configuration? Would it work if you removed those parts you don't need?

Comment: As the error message suggest `location allowOverride` can not be changed. If you dont need it remove it.

Comment: If I remove customErrors tag I'll get an error of customErrors tag needed inside there and if I remove securityPolicy I'll get an error of Security Exception.

Comment: When I remove location tag there is still same error.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that you get exactly the same error if you remove any reference to `location` in the web.config?

Comment: Deleted the web.config from hosting and uploaded it once again. Believe me, still same error occurs.

Comment: You get EXACTLY the same error message?

Comment: EXACTLY same error :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS - this configuration section cannot be used at this path (configuration locking?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock)

Comment: Ramesh, did it and still... same error occurs..

Comment: Try removing the `<trustLevel name="Full"/>`. Many hosting providers do not allow this to be changed.

Comment: Made an edit just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an `.mdf` file you need to have the **Full** trust level (See [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/preparing-databases) for details, in the *Entity Framework and Universal Providers* section).

Your hosting provider does not allow you to change the trust level, so having the `<trustLevel name="Full"/>` directive causes the original error.

Removing the `<trustLevel name="Full"/>` directive the original error is resolved but then you get a security exception since your web application still requires the **Full** trust level to run, which your hosting provider does not provide.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Now I know, that I need to change my hosting provider, because this one doesn't give me opportunity to change trust level.

Comment: Yes, you could change a hosting provider but most hosting providers do not offer full trust, especially in shared hosting environments. Alternatively, you could change your web application to not using .mdf files but use a database located in a Sql Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tasos. I ask my hosting company and they say: Pleks panel does not let trust level full but Maestro panel lets trust level full.

Answer (score 3):

The current versions of ASP.NET now only support full trust.you need to find hosting provider that support Full Trust. For example [asphostportal](http://asphostportal.com/) or [hostforlife](http://hostforlife.eu/)

Answer (score 0):

```
write \\ in connectionstring.

 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Lampino.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```