# Security Exception in Web.Config On Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security

When I am using

```
<trust level="Full"/>
```

in Web.Config it gives error:

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at
>   this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access
>   to this section using  from an
>   inherited configuration file.

But When I **skip trust level**, it gives error

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly
>   does not allow partially trusted callers.

I had also added `[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` in AssemblyInfo.cs,
but it could not help.

Any Help will be great.

My Web.Config:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--

<configuration>
<configSections>

     <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
   </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

        // Here is my connection string
    </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
 <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 </appSettings>



   <system.web>

 <customErrors mode="Off"/>


  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  </roleManager>


   <pages>
    <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    </namespaces>
   </pages>


  </system.web>

<system.webServer>
```

Comment: Its on Online Server. Its not on local

Comment: This post identified why such error happened and how to overcome it [Security Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742550/web-config-configuration-error-in-app)

Comment: Removing trust level not solving my problem.

Comment: *Its on Online Server. Its not on local*, eh? that question is talking about IIS, this is online. You need alter the configuration of IIS, it's not set up correctly. i.e. [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12867753/542251)

Comment: Contact the server administrator. He's the one who probably set the Security Level too low.