# Publishing WebAPI to api folder of an angular application on IIS gives 500 errors on request.

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an angular application with a webAPI 2 backend.  I'm developing them entirely independently (in different repositories, different directories, etc.  The angular project isn't a visual studio project at all.  I'm using WebStorm for it).

Both the front and the backend are working great when debugging, but I can't figure out how to get the backend to work when deploying.  I deployed it to `<application>/api` and I put the angular application in `<application>`.

However, whenever I go to `<application.com>/api`, I get a 500 error.  I also get a 500 whenever I call it from the angular app.

In IIS, I created a Website where the application lives.  I clicked on the api folder and converted it to an Application.  Is there anything else I need to be doing?

Comment: what is the 500 error? Can you attach a debugger to your web api and get some details as to what may be happening? It's entirely too broad as of now to share any sort of guidance with you

Comment: I know.. sorry for the super vague-ness.  What kind of debugger do you recommend?  Outside of debugging through visual studio, I've never debugged in "production"

Comment: you should be able to get something in the network tab in your browser if you drill into that 500 error. Look for a raw response of sort and see if any details are in there. Also, you should be able to attach the debugger to IIS, look for debug => attach to process => `w3wp.exe`

Comment: Also I should have mentioned it's just the debugger from visual studio, w3wp.exe is the IIS windows process

Comment: Hey have you made any forward progress on this? Were you able to drill into that error some more?

Comment: I sadly was not.  I was busy all day yesterday and haven't had time to sit down at my pc to try to figure it out.  I'm going to look into it some more tonight.  I tried publishing the API separately from the angular application and I still can't hit it, so I think it might be something with how my IIS is set up.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to let you know, this post solved it for me, in case you were curious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up having to follow this post to fix it.

> - Click "Start button"
> - in the search box, enter "Turn windows features on or off"
> - in the features window, Click: "Internet Information Services"
> - Click: "World Wide Web Services"
> - Click: "Application Development Features"
> - Check (enable) the features. I checked all but CGI.

[IIS - this configuration section cannot be used at this path (configuration locking?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock)