# Website will not start in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, but works fine in 2013 Pro

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I'm having a problem running a website from VS 2015 Enterprise, where I don't have an issue running it from VS 2013 Pro. The error I get is:

```
This configuration section cannot be used at this path.
This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default
(overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny"
or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

Error Code: 0x80070021

Config Source:

```
<authentication>
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" /> <-- this line is red
</authentication>
```

I have also set the machine.config values to `Allow` for all tags, as well as the applicationhost.

Also, when trying to run it directly from the IIS Server Manager (pointing to the same location as the source files), I get a `503 Service Unavailable`.

I can provide more information if needed.

Other solutions I have tried:

- https://serverfault.com/a/221501
- https://serverfault.com/a/516921
- https://serverfault.com/a/560492
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867753
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12343141
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10390085

Comment: See if [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/360438/iis-complains-about-a-locked-section-how-can-i-find-out-where-its-locked) answer helps

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work. I've updated the OP with the answers I've tried so far.

Comment: I am just guessing... but see if there are  applicationhost.config file(s) at the following locations. 1. C:\Users[your user name]\Documents\IISExpress\config\. 2. In a Config folder in the solution/project directory

Comment: Only the one in the Documents folder existed, and everything in there was set to allow with no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by modifying the applicationhost.config file, within the .vs folder of my solution, and marking the specified elements to allow override.