# ImageResizer deployment integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, imageresizer, integrated-pipeline-mode

I am having problems with deploying a little test project I have made with ImageResizer.

It is basically the most simple version that you can have with a few html pages and then the ImageResizer plugin.

It works locally when I run it from Visual Studio 2013, but after publishing to the server then all I get is a 500 error (even with detailed error messages enabled).

I cannot see the resizer.debug.ashx page either so this is some very basic setup issue  I guess.

My web.config file looks like this (both in VS and on server):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection,ImageResizer" />
  </configSections>

  <resizer>
    <!-- Unless you (a) use Integrated mode, or (b) map all reqeusts to ASP.NET, 
     you'll need to add .ashx to your image URLs: image.jpg.ashx?width=200&height=20 -->
    <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />

    <plugins>
      <!-- <add name="DiskCache" /> -->
      <!-- <add name="PrettyGifs" /> -->
    </plugins>
    <!--<sizelimits imageWidth="0" imageHeight="0" totalWidth="4096" totalHeight="4096" totalBehavior="throwexception"/>-->
  </resizer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>  
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <!-- This is for IIS7+ Integrated mode -->
      <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have verified that 4.6.1 is installed on the server (windows server 2012R2) and that the IIS 8.5 app pool is set to integrated + .net CLR version 4.0.30319.

I have tried playing around with the classic mode as well, but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was something so basic with the setup and did not have anything to do with ImageResizer.

The answer to the question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock) (was missing to turn on Application development for the IIS server)