# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable in IIS?

Tags: c#, iis

I published my Web Api (framework 4.5) in this path:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebAPI
```

In my IIS, I converted this folder to an app

When i try to access this URL http://localhost/MyWebAPI/api/client/1 the message appears:

> **Service Unavailable**
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Why is this?

#### Update

My App Pool is set to be "STOP".  When I turn it on, it goes back to "STOP"

Comment: It seems that your site is not running. Please check in IIS. There is something wrong with IIS configuration.

Comment: A 503 error isn't enough information to diagnose anything.  You'll need to provide more detail.

Comment: so the url is correct right?...the problem must be the configuration in IIs right?

Comment: We can't tell you.  A 503 error isn't enough information to diagnose anything. You'll need to provide more detail.

Comment: Could be crashing on start. Check event viewer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution

- Click on Application Pools under the tree with your machine name,
- on the right side, click click on Advanced Settings,
- in Process Model change the "Load User Profile" to false
- Start your application and restart your IIS

The error will surely change, in my case the error changed to this one

> "Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.
> This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is
> either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a
> location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy
> allowOverride="false"."

I have found the solution for this other problem here
[Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock/12867753#12867753)

Comment: Jesus H Christ, my user in the app pool was stopped. Restarting it fixed the issue. Thank kind stranger.

Comment: This is work for me, I can see the app pool is stopped, and auto-stop due to identity issue. Just change the identity user, work fine!

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in PowerShell in administrator mode.

1. `Stop-Service -Force WAS`
2. `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\*`

   - **If the above command not working, delete files manually.**
3. `Start-Service W3SVC`

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly old thread, but I stumbled across it with the same issue. For me, the resolution was to reset the App Pool user. I was starting the site, but the app pool would just stop. No logs, nothing. I recently had to change my windows password and the app pool user (me) was using the old password :-)

(note my website continued to work for a few days with the old password until I did  an iisreset which is when the problem started)

Answer (score 0):

You might stop App pool, start it and error will be gone.