# How consume rest service that was built using webapi in Visual Studio and published in IIS

Tags: rest, iis, asp.net-web-api, ip-address, publish

I has built a REST service follow to tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeIE3jzAxHU

I has published it in IIS  using Visual Studio. But I don't understand how consume it. In the sample that works under IIS Express it is called as
       localhost:port/api/person.
 When I publish the service in IIS I see many compiled files but I do not understand what address I should call to get the same result as it was under IIS Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get url:

- Open IIS
- Expand out the left tree until you see `Sites`
- Select the one you made for the demo
- Click on `Browse *:port` under `Browse Website` heading on far right pane.

That will give you the base site url for your testing, and just add `api/person` to it from there.

Likely http://localhost/api/person, unless the demo was really weird. If you are unable to still browse the site, give us more information (errors?) or at least screenshots.

Comment: I got error: Config Error    This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".  I wanted add screenshot but I don't see here such possibility

Comment: I think that the problem is solved. In the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock I found and used this sugesstion: Open "Turn windows features on or off" by: WinKey+ R => "optionalfeatures" => OK ; Enable those features under "Application Development Features" After I did it I got right result. Thank you in any case. If you don't have any comments I'll close this question

Comment: @eug100 Glad you got it to work. Hopefully this gives a nice taste of what is to come in terms of sys admin side of hosting :)