# "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" after installing VS 2015 update 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-10

After installing Update 2 for Visual Studio 2015, when trying to debug any web project I keep getting the error message: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow after installing this update, IIS 10 just lost the assignment to the SSL certificate that I had set up for HTTPS. The error message was gone after reassigning the certificate following these steps:

1. In Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, in the Connections pane, expand the name of the server on which the certificate was installed. Then expand Sites and click the site you want to secure using the SSL certificate.
2. In the Actions menu (right pane), click Bindings.
3. In the Site Bindings window, click Add.
4. In the Add Site Binding window, select your SSL certificate in the drop-down list then click OK.

After solving this, when trying to debug, the following error message started to appear:

"Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path".

This problem was solved with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867753).