# Web API Windows Authentication hosting in IIS

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am working on `WEB API` `Windows` `Authentication`. I have added below config in `web.config`

Getting this issue:

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path.

This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default `(overrideModeDefault="Deny")`, or set explicitly by a location tag with `overrideMode="Deny"` or the legacy `allowOverride="false"`

Please help me on this. Please provide steps how to achieve window authentication in web api

Answer (score 1):

> The reason why this error encounters is probably because of the 
>   settings to enable windowsauthentication in IIS via the
>   web.config file. To resolve this you have to adjust the applicationhost.config file of the IIS server. You need to tell IIS that his own configuration may be overwritten:

- For IIS Express follow [these](https://digitaldrummerj.me/iis-express-windows-authentication/) instructions
- For IIS Server follow '[section applicationhost.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)'

> Below steps (simple scenario) to allow windows authentication

1. Assure the webapi project is using windows authentication.

```cs
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
 </system.web>
```

2. Set IIS to windowsAuthenthication and nothing else by configuring the config file

```cs
  <system.webServer>
        <security>
              <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="false"/>
              </authentication>
            </security> 
 </system.webServer>
```

3. Adjust the applicationhost.config of IIS like described above.