# Server Manager opens up whenever i try to open "Turn Windows features on or off"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 application and i have AWS server to deploy it to. In my remote desktop i have placed by code in wwwroot directory in inetpub. Whenever i try to browse my application it gives me 500 Internal Server Error.

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

I looked for the solution and found that problem lies in IIS according to this URL [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path)

But when i click Turn Windows features on or off in the windows menu or through control, it always open Server Manager. Can somebody tell me why this happens or how to apply the changes mentioned in the url i have specified above. 
Thanks

Comment: Try the steps outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44315944/866021 - in Server Manager, in the Manage menu, click `add Roles and Features`. You should see the features you want there.

Comment: Windows 7/8.x/10 use a dedicate management UI, while Windows Server always uses Server Manager. You need to get used to such differences and learn how to use Server Manager to accomplish the same.

Comment: @LexLi I'm using Windows 10 in my machine and i can open Windows Features the way i'm asking here.

Comment: You'd better show a few screenshots. Windows 10 has no Server Manager, unless you give some proof that I am wrong.