# I am getting the following error while running the same application on a different machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

Config Error       This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
Config File    \?\C:\GitSrsCodes\IMS\IMS.Web\web.config. There is an image I am attaching as well: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPzKn.png)

Any help and advise would be very helpful - thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path)

Comment: Yes I solved my problem thank you so much, do you want me to delete this post? What is better option, I posted which exactly fixed my issue but still if its better to remove this post itself I can

Answer (score 1):

The following approach has helped me in fixing the above issue:
Look for the following lines

```
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
<add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
Change those lines to

<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />
<add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />
```